# Limit of a sequence in a topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have this topological space $(\mathbb{R},\sigma)$ where $$\sigma=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z},C_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{N},C_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R}\}$$

Is the sequence $(\frac1n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ has no limit in $(\mathbb{R},\sigma)$ or it's limit is any $x$ such that $ x\in\{\frac{p}{q},~p,q~\text{ are coprime numbers}\}$

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take any $q\in \Bbb{Q}-\Bbb{Z}$. The only open sets containing $q$ are $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$. They both contain all of the sequence. So $q$ is a limit.

Now take any $x\in \Bbb{Z} \cup \Bbb{Q}^c$. Then $x$ belongs to the open set $x\in \Bbb{Z} \cup \Bbb{Q}^c$ which does not contain any element of the sequence (except 1). So $x$ is not a limit.

Therefore, the limits of this sequence are exactly the elements of $q\in \Bbb{Q}-\Bbb{Z}=x\in\{\frac{p}{q},~p,q~\text{ are coprime numbers}\}$.